# Bootstrap tab: strange behaviour in ios chrome

Tags: jquery, ios, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I noticed very strange behaviour of bootstrap tab plugin in my iOS chrome browser. When I click on tab once - chrome shows its loading bar (blue line under the address field), I click on other tab - the bar is hide. One again I click on tab - the bar is visible. See the attachments. All tabs are without any ajax-loaded content. The latest version.

Had somebody same issues maybe?

Thank you

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your tabs must have a link like `href="#idOfContent"`. The `#` is added to the URL when you click on them so it shows to tell user url was changed. But that's strange because the tabs plugin should've preventDefault to not occur that

Comment: Yes, I have an `href="#tabId"`. I is strange because the desktop version works fine

Comment: In iOS you can switch tabs fine (without reloading the page), it just shows the url bar again right? Could you try add `$('ul.classOfUlTab li a').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});` (where `classOfUlTab ` is the real class of your ul) just before your js that initiate the tabs?

Comment: @RaphaelDDL Yes, it helped. But strange that it works fine in Safari. In addition I do not use any javascript to initialize tabs, it's done via html attributes.

Comment: Maybe bootstrap tabs has issues with initializing via `data-*`. Well, glad it helped. Want me to post as an answer?

Comment: Maybe... I will try to investigate this issue but you can an answer. Thanks for help!

Comment: You can post an aswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try prevent the default behavior of the links by adding this inside your document ready.

```
$('ul.classOfUlTab li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This will works because will prevent the `#nnn`(id of current tab) that is pushed to the url (thus showing address bar again).

The only downside I think of it now is that the `#nnn` will not update on the url. Can't remember if tabs load the proper one when you refresh the page but if it does, then you lost that functionality (which enables the 'back' of browser to go to previous tab).